# Unknown label type scikitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to make a Stock Price Classifier, but I always get the same error:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("aapl.csv")
X_data = np.array(data["Open"])
X = []
y = np.array(data["Close"])
for i in range(0, len(X_data)):
    X.append([[X_data[i]]])
X = np.array(X)

X = X.reshape(len(X), 1)
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(20, ),        random_state=1)
clf.fit(X , y)
print("Training set score: %f" % clf.score(X, y))
#print("Test set score: %f" % clf.score(X, y))
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ 136.66, 136.53, 137.11, ..., 100.75, 100.53, 96.69]),)
```

Comment: Is the array shown in the error contents of your `y`? If so, then it seems to be a regression problem, not a classification. Can you show some samples from `aapl.csv` and describe about what you want to do with `Open` and `Close` column. Stock price determination is IMO not a classification task